# AWS ALB inbound requests/traffic and denial of wallet attacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-alb, amazon-waf

Scenario: I have an AWS ALB protected by AWS WAF with lots of AWS Managed WAF Rules, rate limiting rules, etc.

I'm having a hard time in understanding why, even requests blocked by WAF, are impacting the ALB's **ProcessedBytes** and **ConsumedLCUs** metrics, implying that those requests will impact ALB billing.

One simple example: I'm using a WAF rule that blocks requests larger than 8,192 bytes, but, if I do a POST request sending, let's say, 1MB using a simple curl invocation, the request is correctly blocked, but I can see the 1MB appear as processed bytes in the metrics (ProcessedBytes and ConsumedLCUs), so this will get billed.

That means anybody in the world could start a "denial of wallet attack" simply POSTing terabytes of data to the ALB, the requests will get blocked by the WAF rules (size limits, rate-limiting, etc..), but those terabytes of processed data will still impact ConsumedLCUs and get billed.

Am I right? And, if so, is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot!